# Facebook login can't load URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have found few topics about this issue here, but nothing helped me yet. This is my first time when I try to implement facebook login to my website (using PHP). I've found some tutorial, went through all the steps and when I wanted to try login, I got error “Error: Can’t Load URL: The domain of this URL isn’t included in the app’s domains”. Here are screenshots of my settings at FB apps manager: 
[image: basic settings - app domains]

[image: fb login settings]

Even when I try to paste redirect URL into their validator, everything seems fine.
[image: screenshot of redirect URL validator]

```
public function getFbLoginUrl()
{
    $fb = new Facebook(array(
        'app_id' => '434864033760844',
        'app_secret' => '<app secret>',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
    ));

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $helper->getAccessToken('https://vinoservis.mobydyk.cz/sign/facebook');

    $permissions = []; // Optional permissions
    $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://vinoservis.mobydyk.cz/sign/facebook', $permissions);

    return $loginURL;
}
```

Comment: Do you get this before the login dialog gets shown, or after, when it has redirected back to your app?

Comment: I just clicked on the login button, new window opened and got this message

Comment: Where can we see this live? https://vinoservis.mobydyk.cz/sign/facebook redirects me to https://vinoservis.mobydyk.cz/?_fid=kux6, and that appears to have some non-working age verification(?), I don’t get past the overlay.

Comment: Sorry I got error in JS, that's why you couldn't skip it. I have already fixed it, seems there went some bad characters to redirect URL, now I get it with this:

`$loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://vinoservis.mobydyk.cz/sign/facebook', $permissions);

$output = htmlspecialchars($loginURL);`

and it works well for me. Anyway, thanks to everybody for help!